# Delete Database and re-create it

Tags: android, database, sqlite

i want every time the database to be deleted,and then create a new one.
This is my code in DBHelper class:

```
public void createEntry(String title, String getagonistiki, String getskor, String getgipedo, String date, String getgoal1, String getgoal2,
            String teliko_skor) {

         try {        


            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(DBHelper.TITLE, title);
            cv.put(DBHelper.AGONISTIKI, getagonistiki);
            cv.put(DBHelper.SKOR, getskor);
            cv.put(DBHelper.GIPEDO, getgipedo);
            cv.put(DBHelper.DATE, date);
            cv.put(DBHelper.GOALA, getgoal1);
            cv.put(DBHelper.GOALB, getgoal2);
            cv.put(DBHelper.DESCRIPTION, teliko_skor);



                ourDatabase.insert("osfpDB", null, cv); 

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Exception in insert :", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


public void deleteAll() {
         try {

                ourDatabase.rawQuery("Delete from osfpDB", null);

              } catch (Exception e) {
               Log.e("Exception in prize delete query", e.toString());
              } }
```

and this is how i call it:

```
HotOrNot entry = new HotOrNot(agones.this);

            entry.open();
entry.deleteAll();
            entry.createEntry(msg.getTitle(), msg.getagonistiki(), msg
                    .getskor(), msg.getgipedo(), msg.getDate(),msg.getgoal1(),msg.getgoal2(),msg.getDescription());



            entry.close();
```

As result, i m getting my list item multiple times,like 1-30 and then 1-30 again etc..Hope it's understandable

Answer (score 0):

i see youre following the new boston tuts :-) so you can simple copy moste off the following code

```
public String getDatabasePath(){
        String path =ourContext.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).toString();
        return path;
    }
```

just put that code into youre HotorNote class then you just wanna make a normal file deletion with the path used 
can't rember how youre deleting files sry